# Generic extends and implements

Tags: java, generics

I don't understand why `Company` compiled. I thought it checked for `extends` but not for `implements`?

```
public interface Employee

public class HourlyEmployee implements Employee

public class Company<T extends Employee>

Company<HourlyEmployee> company = new Company<>();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `extends` keyword in Generics has a slightly different semantics than the general `extends` keyword.

When using `extends` in the context of Generics, for example `T extends Something`, this means that `T` should be a type that *either* implements the interface `Something` (in cases when `Something` is interface), *or* is a subclass of `Something` (in case `Something` is a class).

Probably the reason for this is that if the `implements` keyword was supported in Generics, this would have made type-parameter declaration too verbose.

For example, you'd have:

```
<T extends SomeClass implements Serializable & Observable>
```

Instead, the valid syntax for this would be:

```
<T extends SomeClass & Serializable & Observable>
```

And you don't need to have the `implements` keyword, actually. When defining the bounds of a type `T`, you just need to point out which *types* does your type `T` derive from, without caring if those are interfaces or classes.

The type definition is not a class definition. You can consider type definition as joining few data sets, where the resulting set is your type `T`.

Answer (score 5):

The notation `T extends Employee` in the declaration of a type parameter refers to either extending a class or implementing an interface.

`public class Company<T implements Employee>` is not a valid syntax.

Therefore `public class Company<T extends Employee>` means that the generic type parameter `T` of your `Company` class must implement the `Employee` interface.